# Extract everything inside tag, but not tag itself

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm using `BeautifulSoup` to scrape text from a website, but I only want the `<p>` tags for organization. However, I can't use `text.findAll('p')`, 
because there are other `<p>` tags that I don't want.

The text I want is all wrapped inside one tag (let's say body), but when I parse it, it takes also includes that tag.

```
link = requests.get('link')
text = bs4.BeautifulSoup(link.text, 'html.parser').find('body')
```

How would I remove the body tag?

Comment: Please provide [mcve]

Comment: do you want all the text indside 'body' tag or all 'p' tags inside 'body'

Comment: post the url or html code

Answer (score 0):

```
text = bs4.BeautifulSoup(link.text, 'html.parser').find('body').text
```

This will concatenate all the text in the `body` tag.

Comment: My reading is that OP wants "everything" inside the tag. Not just the text.

Comment: And moreover it will find only the first element, not every text inside the body.

Answer (score 0):

If you want *everything* in the tag (including HTML), but not the tag itself, you can use the decode_contents method of the Tag class. This will render the **contents** of the tag as a Unicode string

```py
>>> html = """
<body>
<p>Hello <b>World</b></p>
<p>Hello again</p>
</body>
"""

>>> body = bs4.BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser').find('body')

>>> body.decode_contents()
'\n<p>Hello <b>World</b></p>\n<p>Hello again</p>\n'
```

I'm not sure if that's exactly what you're asking for because the question was a little ambiguous so here are the other similar options that you or others may be seeking:

```py
>>> body.text
'\nHello World\nHello again\n'

>>> str(body)
'<body>\n<p>Hello <b>World</b></p>\n<p>Hello again</p>\n</body>'

>>> body.contents
['\n', <p>Hello <b>World</b></p>, '\n', <p>Hello again</p>, '\n']

>>> [p.text for p in body.find_all('p')]
['Hello World', 'Hello again']

>>> list(body.strings)
['\n', 'Hello ', 'World', '\n', 'Hello again', '\n']
```

Answer (score -1):

This may help you:

```
>>> txt = """\
<p>Rahul</p>
<p><i>White</i></p>
<p>City <b>Beston</b></p>
"""

>>> soup = BeautifulSoup(txt, "html.parser")
>>> print("".join(soup.strings))

Rahul
White
City Beston
```

OR you can do this:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
bodyTag = soup.find('body')
bodyText = BeautifulSoup(bodyTag, "html.parser")
print bodyText.strings
```